# Прописная или строчная в названиях

Tags: орфография, названия

1. "Русское географическое общество", "Федеральное бюро расследований" - если в тексте сначала встречается полное название, а потом просто "о/Общество", "Б/бюро"? Текст художественный.
2. Парк п/Почтальона в Лондоне?
3. "Эпоха Т/террора" - про казни после Французской революции? В "Академосе" зафиксирован только "Большой террор (*в СССР в 30-х гг.*)". Или ориентироваться на "эпоху Возрождения" и тогда Террор?

Answer (score 1):

1. Правильно: ***"Русское географическое общество", "Федеральное бюро расследований***". Это имена собственные, названия известных  организаций. Первое слово входит в названия, в этом можно убедиться, если посмотреть в Википедию.
2. Правильно: ***Парк  Почтальона.*** Ищем походящие тексты, где название находится в середине предложения.  Слово «Парк» входит название. Дело в том, что здесь **грамматическая** связь, управление Р.п.
3. Правильно:  ***«Большой террор»***  в СССР и ***«Террор»***  во Франции.   Это название определенного исторического периода,  причем именно в таком виде. В этом можно убедиться по материалам из Википедии и  по другим осточникам, где названия используются с середине предложения. Слово «*Большой*» имеет **условное** значение, поэтому входит в название.
4. ***Возрождение, эпоха Возрождения***:  применяются **оба** названия,  причем во втором случае приложение  находится перед именем собственным, например:

***Возрождение** (иначе — Ренессанс) — название эпохи в истории западноевропейской культуры, Отличительная черта **эпохи Возрождения** — светский характер культуры и её антропоцентризм (то есть интерес, в первую очередь, к человеку и его деятельности).*

Comment: 1. Тут вопрос не про полное название, а про сокращенное - общество или Общество (если имеется в виду Русское географическое общество).

Comment: Это по тексту смотрите.  Если сначала там использовали полное название, (Русское географическое общество), то потом  (в этом тексте) могут использовать сокращенное (Общество/общество).  Читателю и так ясно, о чем речь, так зачем повторяться. А вот Бюро/бюро вряд ли подойдет. Можно: эпоха Террора.

Comment: А вообще говоря, уместность замены надо смотреть по тексту.  Не видя тест и само предложение, а также не учитывая стилевые особенности, сложно определить что-либо.  Можно говорить только о том, какая замена нежелательна.